# DirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule Appears to work, but really doesn't

Tags: c#, file, security

I have an application that is intended to add read/execute permissions for a user.  It appears to work, but really doesn't.

I have the following code:

```
string folderName = @"\\ShareDrive\MyDepartment\someFolder";
        DirectorySecurity ds = new DirectoryInfo(folderName).GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);
            AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = ds.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

        ds.AddAccessRule(
            new FileSystemAccessRule(
                "SomeValidUser@myCompany.com",
                FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute,
                InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                PropagationFlags.None,
                AccessControlType.Allow));

        
        rules = ds.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
        //when I examine the value of 'rules' after executing the above statement, it appears the person has been added with
        //the correct identity reference (successfully translated the email address)
```

After executing this code, if I check permissions in Windows File Explorer, the person has NOT been added.  This is actually expected since if I try to add the person in File Explorer, I get an access denied error.  I was expecting AddAccessRule to throw an exception.

My question is:  How can I in C# check to see if the operation actually succeeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`SetAccessControl()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemaclextensions.setaccesscontrol?view=net-5.0#System_IO_FileSystemAclExtensions_SetAccessControl_System_IO_DirectoryInfo_System_Security_AccessControl_DirectorySecurity_) passing in your modified `DirectorySecurity` object to actually apply your changes.

Comment: SetAccessControl() throws the expected exception.  It  is a function of System.IO.FileSystemAclExtensions which is only available in .net 5, so I had to convert my app to .net (as opposed to .net framework)

Comment: @MarkAinsworth There's also [`DirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.setaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8) in .NET Framework.